# Testing automation tool suited for operation team

Tags: linux, testing, automated-tests, load-testing

I would like to start using an testing framework that does the following:

- contains an process(the process can be a test) management engine. It is able to start processes(tests) with the help of a scheduler
- it is distributed, processes can run locally or on other machines
- tests can be anything:
- simple telnet on a given port (infrastructure testing)
- a disk I/O or mysql benckmark
- a jar exported from Selenium that does acceptance testing
- will need to know if the test passed or not
- has the capability to get real time data from the test(something like graphite) -- this is optional
- allows processes to be build in many programing languages: perl, ruby, C, bash
- has a graphical interface
- open-source
- written in any language as long as it doesn't use resources , I would prefer C, perl or ruby
- to run on linux 
  What not to be:
- an add on to a browser: Selenium, BITE ..

I do not want something focused on web development

I will like to use such a tool or maybe collaborate on building one. I hope I was explicit enough. Thank you .

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at the [robot framework](http://www.robotframework.org) combined with [jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/). Robotframework is a tool written in python for doing keyword-based acceptance testing. Jenkins is a continuous integration tool which allows you to schedule jobs, and distribute jobs amongst a grid of nodes.

Robotframework tests can do anything python can do, plus a whole lot more. It has a remote interface, which means you can write test keywords in just about any language. For example, I had a job where we had keywords written in Java. In another job we used robotframework with .NET-based keywords. This can be accomplished via a remote interface (so you can write keywords in many different languages) or you can run robot using jython to run on the JVM, or iron python to run in a .NET environment.

Comment: Hello, I found STAF. STAF=Software Testing Automation Framework. It uses STAX and is able to do just about any of the requests I needed.